# Get list of Chat rooms id from firebase firestore using the current user id in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try many times and many way to get the chat_rooms from firestore but i get an empty list []

[image: this is my firestore data]
[image]

I try this

```
void fetchMessages(String currentID) async {
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat_rooms').get();
  
  print("Number of documents: ${snapshot.docs.length}");

  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document in snapshot.docs) {
   
    if (document.id.contains(currentID)) {

      var message = document.data()['message'];
      print('Message: $message');
    }
  }
}
```

and i get Number of documents: 0

Comment: Check what it says in the bottom right of your first screenshot: "This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots". So: there is actually no Ωdocument "IEan..." or any of the ones for which the ID is shown in italic. The console merely shows those IDs, because there is content in subcollections. If you want to be able to query the `chat_rooms` directly, you will need to ensure that those documents exist.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Is this the link how to fix it [link] (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console?hl=en&authuser=0&_gl=1*7056al*_ga*NTMyODcyOTAyLjE3MDY4OTgxNTE.*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTcwODYzMTg1OC4zMy4xLjE3MDg2MzIyNTkuNTguMC4w#query_data). if yes should i use collection or group collection?

Comment: "fix it" is not clear here, but as said in the message in the screenshot and in the links: there is not way to get those IDs back from a query, as there are no documents at that path.

Comment: I get the solution which is to add a field inside the docs. or the second solution is to add field of array 'chated_with', which i have on it the uids of the other users that have room chat with current user